# CSGO command drop your FPS

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Yesterday when I login into my friend's steam account and play *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, I found that before I enter my own config setting, the default config setting of the game can run above 200+ FPS.

But after when I enter my config setting, the FPS began to drop until 100-120 FPS. Just like my main account. So I wanna ask is there any list of specific command show that which command will drop the FPS?

Below is the config setting that I used.

#### Other setting:

```
bind mwheelup +jump; bind mwheeldown +jump; bind "c" "+speed; r_cleardecals; +cl_show_team_equipment; cl_disablefreezecam 1; cl_use_opens_buy_menu 0; fps_max 0; net_graphproportionalfont 0; cl_showpos 1; viewmodel_fov 68;
```

#### Crosshair config:

```
cl_crosshairsize 1; cl_crosshairgap -1; cl_crosshairthickness 1; cl_crosshaircolor 5; cl_crosshaircolor_b 255; cl_crosshaircolor_g 255; cl_crosshaircolor_r 255; cl_crosshairdot 0; cl_crosshairstyle 4; cl_crosshairalpha 250; cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue 0; cl_crosshairusealpha 1; cl_crosshair_drawoutline 1;
```

#### Bob Config:

```
cl_bob_lower_amt "5"; cl_bobamt_lat "0.1"; cl_bobamt_vert "0.1" cl_bobcycle "0.98"; cl_viewmodel_shift_left_amt "0.5"; cl_viewmodel_shift_right_amt "0.25";
```

Comment: If you wanna check my PC spec I can post too.

Comment: Have you tried applying your configuration settings one at a time?

Comment: Was there a specific command where it dropped noticeably, or did each command reduce it very slightly?

Comment: I suspect it was the bob config or the viewmodel config but is there any case say that these command will affect the FPS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use either `cl_showfps 1` or `net_graph 1` to view your FPS. Remove the config and input each line manually into the console to help you understand when your FPS drops. There is no console command to show what specific setting is lowering your FPS.

Comment: yes, how I know my fps drop because I got use `net_graph 1` to view my fps, but I found that probably it's because I enter the bob config and my fps is drop.

Comment: As you mention that there is no console command will lower my fps, can you show me the default config setting? Maybe I can set back to default to make my FPS more higher.

Comment: Consider deleting your configs and verifying the integrity of the in-game files to restore the original configs.

Comment: I guess it was my graphic card problem... After upgraded my graphic card, the FPS is maintain back to 200++.